# How can I fix "'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?

Tags: cmd

I'm trying to run a file on my Windows 10 Pro and this file when I run should build the ui of a code of a website, but when I type in './ui/build' it only shows this error,

> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

I tried '.\ui\build' instead of './ui/build', but that to resulted in the same error,

> '.\ui\build' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

How am I to run a file, so that it builds in my terminal?

Comment: In general that would work (with or without the leading dot-backlsash). Are you sure that the current (working) directory has a subdirectory `ui` with a file `build`(.cmd) in there? Also, what is the value of PATHEXT (do `echo %PATHEXT%` )?

Comment: You seem not to try to run a file but a directory…

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Linux, the Windows command line does look in the current directory by default, so you don't need a dot at all. Try `ui\build`.

Comment: Yes I have tried that, "'ui\build' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."